# How can i prematurely close an ajax call from php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

okay so,

`[browser] ==> makes AJAX call to webserver running php`

i have the following php code,

```
<?php

  //Process Ajax request
  //return success code to browser

  //continue with other php code
 ?>
```

How exactly can i achieve the second part i.e "return success code to browser"? and continue with processing php code.

Comment: you could use output buffers and the `flush();` function to push some output to the browser before your script has completed. further reading here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

```
     put **async:false** in ajax call so your code will execute synchronously  means  until you don't get success or failure from ajax return rest of code will not execute .. do like following

   // add here jquery file 
   <script>
     $.ajax({
            url : "abc.com/page",
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            async:false
            success : function(data)
            {
               //you can use data here
            }
    });
   </script>
   //you can write here php code
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it can be done like follow

```
 //initial php code
 call_function();

 echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));

 //other php code
 call_function(); //etc
```

or you can split the ajax call in 2 parts.. in 1st part it will get the status so echo json_encode() will be executed and call ends and in success call back of ajax make 2nd call which will execute the remaining code!

Comment: It can't, since php is executed entirely first. That means that echo would "appear" only after call_function() is done.

Comment: yes i know thats why i have given you 2nd choice split the call in 2 parts!

Comment: Your answer is simply wrong.